# How to run "docker run hello-world" using AWS Batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-volume, aws-batch

I have build using boto3 a workflow that creates a compute environment, creates a job queue, registers a job definition and finally submits job. Trying 'ls' command works fine, however, when trying command 'docker run hello-world' does not work.

Code to create comp env:

```
response = client.create_compute_environment(
        computeEnvironmentName=com_env_name,
        type='MANAGED',
        state='ENABLED',
        computeResources={
            'type': 'EC2',
            'allocationStrategy': 'BEST_FIT',
            'minvCpus': 0,
            'maxvCpus': 5,
            'instanceTypes': [
                'c3.large',
            ],
            'ec2Configuration': [{
                'imageType': 'ECS_AL2',
            }],
            'subnets': [
                subnet_id,
            ],
            
            'securityGroupIds': [
                sec_gr_id,
            ],
            'instanceRole': 'ecsInstanceRole', 
        },
        serviceRole = 'arn:aws:iam::blabla
 )
```

The job queue is defined as:

```
response = batch_client.create_job_queue(
            jobQueueName=queue_name,
            state='ENABLED',
            priority=1,
            computeEnvironmentOrder=[
                {
                    'order': 1,
                    'computeEnvironment': com_env_name
                },
            ],
        )
```

My goal is to run 'docker run hello-world'. The job definition is defined as follows:

```
response = batch.register_job_definition(
            jobDefinitionName=job_def_name,
            type='container',
            containerProperties={
                'image': 'custom-image',
                'memory': 2048,
                'vcpus': 2,
                'command': ['ls'],
                'environment': [
                                {
                                    'name': "DOCKER_HOST",
                                    'value': "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
                                },
                            ],
                'volumes': [
                        {
                            'host': {
                                'sourcePath': '//var/run/docker.sock'
                            },
                            'name': 'docker'
                        }],
                'mountPoints': [
                        {
                            'containerPath': '/var/run/docker.sock',
                            'sourceVolume': 'docker'
                        }],
            },
        )
```

Are the volumes and mount points properly set? What is missing? Is there a connection between dockers to establish? The output **error** after submitting the job is:

**CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "docker run hello-world": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown**

The code for job submission is:

```
        response = batch.submit_job(
            jobDefinition=job_def_name,
            jobName=job_nom,
            jobQueue=job_queue_name,
            containerOverrides={
                'command': ['docker run hello-world',]
            }
```

Comment: What docker image is `custom-image`? The error is pretty clear. The docker container you are running doesn't have a `custom-image` executable

Answer (score 0):

I notice two things:

- You have an extra slash in your `sourcePath`
- The error message you get seems to indicate that the docker executable doesn't exist in the image you're running. You'll need to use an image that supports docker in docker, such as the standard [docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) image

Comment: my custom image has docker installed. Locally, if I try to run docker inside my custom image it WORKS. So I do not understand why the the docker executable is not found. The extra slash does not seem to affect as it does not works as with only 1.